# apk tool gives permission denied

Tags: virtual-machine, docker, alpine-linux

I get this error message running alpine linux in a docker container hosted by Ubuntu 18.04 in Vagrant with its host in turn being Windows 10 behind a proxy. I have [set the proxy variables](https://github.com/gliderlabs/docker-alpine/issues/191#issuecomment-246944011) but still get the same error.

```
/ # apk update
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.8/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
ERROR: http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.8/main: Permission denied
WARNING: Ignoring APKINDEX.adfa7ceb.tar.gz: No such file or directory
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.8/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
ERROR: http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.8/community: Permission denied
WARNING: Ignoring APKINDEX.efaa1f73.tar.gz: No such file or directory
2 errors; 13 distinct packages available
/ #
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was getting the same symptoms until I followed the steps in [Docker network config](https://docs.docker.com/network/proxy/).

- `vi ~/.docker/config.json`
- Add a `proxies` json section updated with your details:

  `,
  "proxies":
  {
    "default":
    {
      "httpProxy": "http://your-proxy-host:your-proxy-port",
      "noProxy": "*.test.example.com,.example2.com"
    }
  }`

Make sure you include the protocol (*http://*) in the `httpProxy` setting, i.e.:

- "httpProxy": "*http://*your-proxy-host..."

**not**

- "httpProxy": "your-proxy-host..."

Once I did this, my `Permission denied` errors disappeared and the fetches were successful.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason I had to run this command in the Ubuntu host:

`sudo ln -sf /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf`

Then it worked.